# Which film inspired Haruhi in "The Sighs of Haruhi Suzumiya"?

Tags: haruhi-suzumiya

In the second Haruhi Suzumiya novel, "*[The Sighs of Haruhi Suzumiya](https://archive.org/details/manga_Suzumiya_Haruhi/Suzumiya%20Haruhi%20-%20Volume%2002%20-%20The%20Sighs%20of%20Suzumiya%20Haruhi%20%5BBaka-Tsuki%5D%5BAlternative%20Layout%5D)*", Haruhi is inspired to make a film with the SOS Brigade after watching a movie, and believing she could do better. (The film they make is adapted as the first episode of the Haruhi Suzumiya anime series, and includes the talking cat, colour changing doves, magic laser beams and unseasonal sakura blossoms caused by Haruhi). At the end of the novel Kyon narrates that the movie was called "Only", and was shown at the Cannes Film Festival.

> Oh yeah, remember that midnight movie that supposedly gave Haruhi the idea of making our
> own film? After some research, I discovered that it didn't win the Golden Globe Award. It was a
> black and white promotional movie which was shown in the Cannes Film Festival called "Only."
> She must've been crazy to think this film would win any award. To confirm this, I even rented
> the film. It turned out that I fell asleep within the first half hour. So I have no idea whether the
> content is fun or boring. I think I'll attempt it again before I return it.

I've tried to search for this movie, but with "only" being such a common word, I was unable to track it down. Was this a real movie? If so, which movie was it? I'm assuming it was a real movie, as the other pop culture references in the novel (Rocky, Bryan Adams, The Great Escape, etc) all seem to be real.

Comment: Hmm. If it was more than 30 mins long, it can't have been [this short film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0758010/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_4). There are only [two other titles on IMDB that match](https://www.imdb.com/find?q=only&s=tt&exact=true&ref_=fn_al_tt_ex), both produced in the last 3 years and both in colour.

Comment: Worthy of mention that this light novel was [published in September 2003](https://haruhi.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sigh_of_Haruhi_Suzumiya_(light_novel)), which means it was probably written no later than 2001-2002.

Comment: The only film that played at Cannes between 1993 and 2004 with the word "Only" in the title was a documentary (in colour) about Soul Music and the history of Stax Records called [Only the Strong Survive](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi381681945?playlistId=tt0308672&ref_=tt_ov_vi)

Comment: My copy of this novel has the film as "*Dake*" (which translates into Japanese as "Only"). It also has an additional line; "*remember the movie that had been broadcast late at night and had given Haruhi the idea of making a film in the first place? Upon further research, I discovered that the movie hadn’t even won a Golden Globe. The movie was something called Dake, which had been screened at the Cannes Film Festival **a fairly long time ago.***"